# Installation of pysftp via pip failed (because of 2 python2.x versions?)

Tags: python, pip, version, pysftp

My Ubuntu 10.04 came with Python 2.6. Now, I also installed Python 2.7, which is the system default now because when I start `python` from the terminal, it starts python 2.7.

Now, I want to install the library pysftp using pip, but I'm having a hard time doing so. Below follow some results of my attempts and conclusions. I did `pip install pysftp`, but it says the following:

```
Downloading/unpacking pysftp
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pysftp
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .dist import _get_unpatched
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
        packaging = pkg_resources.packaging
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

    from setuptools.extension import Extension

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>

    from .dist import _get_unpatched

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>

    packaging = pkg_resources.packaging

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in ./pip-log.txt
```

It seems to me that pip (which was obviously installed before Python 2.7 was installed) links to the old version of Python, which doesn't support pysftp. Also because when I do `pip --version` it says:

```
pip 0.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)
```

When I do `whereis python`, it gives me the following information:

```
python: /usr/src/Python-2.7.10/python /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /etc/python2.6 /etc/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib/python3.1 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python3.1 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

How can I install pysftp?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall `pip` for Python 2.7, then run `pip2.7 install pysftp`. You need a `pip` installation for each version of Python you want to use it with. The [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) package is probably the easiest way to get going; you can simply run the following to do it all in one fell swoop:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O --no-check-certificate - | sudo python2.7 && sudo easy_install-2.7 pip && sudo pip2.7 install pysftp
```

Sometimes older Linux installs have issues with the above command, due to an "invalid" certificate encounted while downloading the full `setuptools` package via `ez_setup.py` ([see here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-wget) for more details). This can be circumvented with this alternative one-fell-swoop command:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-18.8.1.zip --no-check-certificate && unzip setuptools-18.8.1.zip && cd setuptools-18.8.1 && sudo python setup.py install && sudo easy_install-2.7 pip && sudo pip2.7 install pysftp
```

Comment: I got a certificate error for the wget command (solved with `--no-check-certificate`). Then the script gives `return status 5` (while calling wget for setuptools). After manually downloading that file, it says `zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`. Help?

Comment: @Lewistrick That's unusual, I can't imagine why it would be trying to unzip something... It's failing on the `sudo python2.7 ez_setup.py` part?

Comment: Yes, it's trying to unzip the local version of `https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-18.8.1.zip`. Is it using the wrong file?

Comment: @Lewistrick That's the same file it downloaded for me. Perhaps there was an error in the download?

Comment: At first, there was. So I downloaded it manually. Then it raised the zip error.

Comment: @Lewistrick Check the `md5sum` of the zip file, I get `2cc2f9c0970bef40f95184639fb97fdc`.

Comment: I get `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`. Also, when trying to open this with archive manager, it says `End-of-central-directory signature not found.`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97880/discussion-between-mego-and-lewistrick).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to install some sort of 'essentials package' using the code

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Then you can install :

```
sudo pip install pysftp
sudo pip install enum
```